# Route not being hit

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an express application with many routes that work fine but today I tried to add a new route and it just seems to no never get hit. I tried with a request from another application of mine and through Postman. Both return just Internal Server Error. However, every other one of my routes work just fine.

For the query in question test is a tinyint(1) and id is an int

Here is the route in question in my User.js route.

```
router.put("/add/:id", function (req, res, next) {
    db.query(
        "UPDATE user SET test = ? WHERE id = ?",
        [1, req.params.id],
        function (error, response) {
            if (error) throw error;

            if (response.affectedRows > 0) {
                res.sendStatus(200);
            } else {
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }
        }
    )
});
```

My postman request:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/user/add/39583
```

Notthing gets hit though, I tried switching out put for post and I tried adding logging within the route but nothing shows. Not even the status is returned, it just says Internal Server Error in Postman

Comment: try  .post("/add") without any id param...if that works

Comment: @RohitasBehera that also returns just Internal Service Error, which is confusing because I have many other routes in this user file that work perfectly fine.

Comment: are you also module.exports = router; or app.use('/', router);
 ??